# Hp pavilion dv7 won't display

Tags: windows-7

I have this hp pavilion dv7 with the following configurations
ram- 2(2gb-2rx8)
hard disk- 160 with a wide screen 17inch windows7 running on it.
Initially,i opened the cass to examine if the rams were the problem,later on to cross-cecked the screen and the inverter but still no display.
my observations:
fan will spine like 20secounds before everything went off again